# What are different ways to express "around"?

Tags: words, nuances, expressions

I understand there are various ways to express the word "around" in Japanese under different contexts. 
I'm not sure of all the words used in each context and I see many variations used, both casual/polite etc.

Here is what I know for example:

1. I will travel "around" the world.
2. Is there a restroom "around" here? この辺り\この辺
3. I will meet you "around" 12:00pm. 頃、くらい\ぐらい
4. He is "around" the library. あそこ
5. He showed me "around" town. あちこち

Are there other ways to express "around"?

Comment: Example 4 might not be a good example, as I don't see how it can be translated as "around" the library. I can see 「あそこら辺」, but it's the same use as example 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 世界｛せかい｝一周｛いっしゅう｝の旅｛たび｝をする - Take a trip around the world
2. この辺り｛あたり｝（この辺｛へん｝）にトイレはありますか？ - Is there a restroom in these parts?
3. 12時前後｛じぜんご｝に会｛あ｝いましょう・12時ごろ会いましょう - Let's meet around 12:00.
4. 図書館｛としょかん｝のそばにいます・図書館の付近｛ふきん｝にいます - He is in the vicinity of the library.
5. 彼｛かれ｝は街｛まち｝を案内｛あんない｝してくれました - He introduced me to the town (showed me 'around')